# Why is plot returning "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" when a dataframe column of floats is being passed to the plot function?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a dataframe I have created from an excel spreadsheet using either matplotlib or matplotlib and pandas ie. df.plot. However, python keeps returning a cannot convert string to float error. This is confusing since when I print the column of the dataframe it appears to be all float values.

I've tried printing the values of the dataframe column and using the pandas.plot syntax. I've also tried saving the column to a new variable.

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import glob
import openpyxl
import math
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side, Alignment
import seaborn as sns
import itertools


directory = 'E:\some directory'
#QA_directory = directory + '**/*COPY.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(directory + '\\Calcs\\' + "excel file.xlsx", data_only = 'True')

plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
axes = plt.axes()
plt.title('Drag Amplification', fontsize = 16)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('Cf', fontsize = 14)

d = pd.DataFrame()
n=[]

for sheets in wb.sheetnames:
    if '2_1' in sheets and '2%' not in sheets and '44%' not in sheets:
        name = sheets[:8]

        print(name)
        ws = wb[sheets]
        data = ws.values
        cols = next(data)[1:]
        data = list(data)
        idx = [r[0] for r in data]
        data = (itertools.islice(r, 1, None) for r in data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=cols)
        df = df.dropna()

        #x = df['x/l']
        #y = df.Cf
        print(df.columns)
        print(df.Cf.values)

        x=df['x/l'].values
        plt.plot(x, df.Cf.values)
        """x = [wb[sheets].cell(row=row,column=1).value for row in range(1,2000) if wb[sheets].cell(row=row,column=1).value]
        print(x)
        Cf = [wb[sheets].cell(row=row,column=6).value for row in range(1,2000) if wb[sheets].cell(row=row,column=1).value]
        d[name+ 'x'] = pd.DataFrame(x)
        d[name + '_Cf'] = pd.Series(Cf, index=d.index)
        print(name)"""
        print(df)
plt.show()
```

I'm expecting a plot of line graphs with the values of x/l on the x access and Cf on the 'y' with a line for each of the relevant sheets in the workbook. Any insights as to why i am getting this error would be appreciated!

Comment: You probably just forgot to convert the strings in your dataframe to floats.

Comment: how would I test this? type(df.iat[2,2]) returned float but I wasn't about to check the whole lot! and printing didn't reveal any random text. Is there a way to convert the whole dataframe quickly and simply without writing a loop?

Comment: `df.info(verbose=True)` would give you the datatypes of all the columns

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - that has helped! - sort of. All of the columns are dtype object so I have tried to convert the column I am most interested in 'x/l' using the code df['x/l']=df['x/l'].astype('float64') but still return the error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x/l'" which is back to the original issue

Comment: https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html provided a good guide to this problem. Eventually this  ````for col in df.columns:
            df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')``` worked although it does seem to be slow. Now I just need to figure out why the plot function is plotting the index rather than the value!